# Is possible to display only records of a given recordType in a related list?

Tags: lightning, record-type, related-list

I have a page layout with a related list of records of a child object. I don't want to display all the child records of this object but only the ones of a given record type. Is it possible to achieve easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out of the box, there's [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrbgAAC) which is now in the Product Team Review status.

You can though use [Doug Ayer's](https://twitter.com/DouglasCAyers) config only [Filter Related Lists without Code](https://douglascayers.com/2015/11/18/salesforce-filter-related-lists-without-code/) (which has worked for me in the past).